# How can I send the "&" (ampersand) character via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, string, post, xmlhttprequest

I want to send a few variables and a string with the `POST` method from JavaScript.

I get the string from the database, and then send it to a PHP page. I am using an `XMLHttpRequest` object.

The problem is that the string contains the character `&` a few times, and the `$_POST` array in PHP sees it like multiple keys.

I tried replacing the `&` with `\&` with the `replace()` function, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Can anyone help?

**The javascript code and the string looks like this:**

```
var wysiwyg = dijit.byId("wysiwyg").get("value");
var wysiwyg_clean = wysiwyg.replace('&','\&');

var poststr = "act=save";

poststr+="&titlu="+frm.value.titlu;
poststr+="&sectiune="+frm.value.sectiune;
poststr+="&wysiwyg="+wysiwyg_clean;
poststr+="&id_text="+frm.value.id_text;

xmlhttp.open("POST","lista_ajax.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(poststr);
```

**The String is:**

```
 <span class="style2">&quot;Busola&quot;</span>
```

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

It will escape all the characters that cannot occur verbatim in URLs:

```
var wysiwyg_clean = encodeURIComponent(wysiwyg);
```

In this example, the ampersand character `&` will be replaced by the escape sequence `%26`, which is valid in URLs.

Comment: Is this enough to securely escape the data or is ist "just" enough to avoid the ampersand issue?

Comment: @Sprottenwels, it is enough to properly encode all the data. What do you mean by "securely" in this context?

Answer (score 15):

You might want to use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

```
encodeURIComponent("&quot;Busola&quot;"); // => %26quot%3BBusola%26quot%3B
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to url-escape the ampersand.  Use:

```
var wysiwyg_clean = wysiwyg.replace('&', '%26');
```

As Wolfram points out, this is nicely handled (along with all the other special characters) by encodeURIComponent.

Answer (score 5):

Ramil Amr's answer works only for the & character. If you have some other special characters, you should use PHP's `htmlspecialchars()` **and** JS's `encodeURIComponent()`.

You can write:

```
var wysiwyg_clean = encodeURIComponent(wysiwyg);
```

And on the server side:

```
htmlspecialchars($_POST['wysiwyg']);
```

This will make sure that AJAX will pass the data as expected, and that PHP (in case your'e insreting the data to a database) will make sure the data works as expected.

Comment: This was helpful thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can pass your arguments using this encodeURIComponent function so you don't have to worry about passing any special characters.

```
data: "param1=getAccNos&param2="+encodeURIComponent('Dolce & Gabbana')
```

OR

```
var someValue = 'Dolce & Gabbana';
data: "param1=getAccNos&param2="+encodeURIComponent(someValue)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 1):

You could encode your string using Base64 encoding on the JavaScript side and then decoding it on the server side with PHP (?).

JavaScript ([Docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa))

```
var wysiwyg_clean = window.btoa( wysiwyg );
```

PHP ([Docu](http://php.net/manual/de/function.base64-decode.php)):

```
var wysiwyg = base64_decode( $_POST['wysiwyg'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way is to use a JavaScript library such as jQuery and set your data option as an object, then let jQuery do the encoding, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/link.json",
  data: { value: poststr },
  error: function(){ alert('some error occured'); }
});
```

If you can't use jQuery (which is pretty much the standard these days), use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_javascript_1.5_reference%3aglobal_functions%3aencodeuricomponent).

Answer (score 0):

```
encodeURIComponent(Your text here);
```

This will truncate special characters.

Comment: This does not add any value to the answers above