# $_GET the value of (&) with AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have three codes the first one is `html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "AJAX.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form method = "GET" >
    <input type = "text" id ="a" ><br>
    <input type = "text" id = "b"><br>
    <input type = "button" value ="click"  onclick = "process()"><br>
    <textarea id = "underbutton" ></textarea><br>
</form>
<body>
</html>
```

Now javaScript (AJAX) :

```
function process() {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){

        a = document.getElementById("a").value;
                b = document.getElementById("b").value;
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.open("GET","file.php?a="+a+"&b="+b,true);
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
}

function handleServerResponse (){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
        {

        response = xmlHttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("underbutton").innerHTML =  response ;


        }

}
```

Now php file :

```
<?php  

echo $_GET['a'].'<br>';
echo $_GET['b'].'<br>';

?>
```

everything is working but the problem is when I type in the first texbox (a) the word `hello` and the second (b) the code `&` and click the button ; it must print out `hello&`.
but it  prints  `hello`!!
just `hello` without `&`.

I noted that I was sending to php file is this :
`file.php?a=hello&b=&`.
the last `&` must be `%26`

So to print out `&` I must send :
`file.php?a=hello&b=%26`.

How can I fix that ??

Comment: You can't, really. The `&` has a special meaning in a query string - it's the parameter separator. It needs to be encoded if you want to include it as a value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294107/how-can-i-send-the-ampersand-character-via-ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change in the JavaScript:

```
- a = document.getElementById("a").value;
- b = document.getElementById("b").value;
+ a = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("a").value);
+ b = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("b").value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to URL-encode your values:

```
xmlHttp.open("GET","file.php?a="+encodeURIComponent(a)+"&b="+encodeURIComponent(b),true);
```

You need this because the parameters in your URL are splitted on '&' and so its like:

**a=hello**
*&*
**b=**
*&*
*(here could be a third parameter)*

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery.AJAX() will take care of the problem for you, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Use encodeURIComponent()

```
xmlHttp.open("GET","file.php?a="+encodeURIComponent(a)+"&b="+encodeURIComponent(b),true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To encode an ampersand (&) in URLs, you use `&amp;`.  What happens when you replace it with that?

Comment: The problem is not with & being in HTML.