# Post variable croped

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I am using some ajax request to access to php file. It's working perfectly exept one part. When I am getting the $_POST value of one of my variable, it crops the end of the word.

```
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'https://myadress.com',
            data: {
                workout: JSON.stringify(workout),
                username: localStorage.getItem('username'),
                workout_name: $('#name').val().toString(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
        });
```

If i alert workout_name before sending it, it displays "test" but when i echo it from my php file, it displays "te".
I am wondering why it's doing that, i can't fix it. I was thinking maybe the size of my other variable are too big...
Here is my php code:

```
 `  if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['workout_name']) && isset($_POST['workout'])) {

        $workout_name = $_POST['workout_name'];
        echo $workout_name;
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $workout = json_decode($_POST['workout']);
}`
```

Thank you for your answer.

**Edit:**
Thanks to the answer, it's working now. I just need to do :

```
workout_name: encodeURIComponent($('#name').val())
```

in my js file and when I retrieve the data in the php file I use :

```
urldecode($_POST['workout_name']);
```

Comment: why do you do this `$('#name').val().toString()`. I mean the `toString` method?

Comment: I am getting the name input by the user. It was stupid, i thought the val() values wasn't a string...

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217958/ajax-post-request-gets-cropped

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem, I put the correction if it can help people.