# Proper way to handle the ampersand character in JSON string send to REST web service

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, datacontractjsonserializer

OK,

I am using the `System.Runtime.Serialization` and the `DataContractJsonSerialization`.

The problem is that in the request I send a value of a property with the `&` character. Say, `AT&T`, and I get a response with error: `Invalid JSON Data`.

I thought that the escaping would be done inside the library but now I see that the serialization is left untouched the ampersand `&` character.

Yes, for a JSON format this is valid. 
But it will be a problem to my POST request since I need to send this to a server that if contains an ampersand will response with error, hence here I am.

`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` is in the `System.Web` library and so the way to go is using `Uri.EscapeUriString`. I did this to try, but anyway, and without it all requests are working fine, except an ampersand is in a value.

EDIT: `HttpUtility` class is ported to the Windows Phone SDK but the prefer way to encode a string should be still `Uri.EscapeUriString`.

First thought was to get hands dirty and start replacing the special character which would cause a problem in the server, but, I wonder, is there another solution I should do, that it would be efficient and 'proper'?

I should tell that I use

```
// Convert the string into a byte array.
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
```

To convert the JSON to a `byte[]` and write to the `Stream`.
And,

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

As the `WebRequest.ContentType`.

So, am I messed up for a reason or something I miss?

Thank you.

Comment: You say that you're sending JSON data, but the content-type says otherwise (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). Can you post more information about how you're sending the data, and how the service is receiving it?

Comment: Even changing it, the server returns 500.

Comment: What do you use on the server? Can you post the server code?

Comment: No i have no access on the server. It's a really strange problem. This should just work. I guess something's wrong with the server, I'll contact the guy handles it.

Comment: Yes, you need to contact the server owner. 500 (Internal Server Error) means something is wrong with the server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that I was encoding the whole request string including the key.
I had a request `data={JSON}` and I was formatting it, but the `{JSON}` part should only be encoded.

```
string requestData = "data=" + Uri.EncodeDataString(json) // worked perfect!
```

Stupid hole to step into.

Comment: No problem. It solves my case, you never know who else could miss something similar. Actually it's a combination client-server contract. The server searches if there is a key "data" in the body and if not takes the whole body trying to deserialize it, then in my case it failed due to ampersand character trying to separate as a parameter.

Comment: It's Uri.EscapeDataString() not Encode...Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried replacing the ampersand with `&amp;` for the POST?

Comment: If I replace & with &amp; it fails as well.

Comment: You should never include a regular ampersand in any kind of URL request payload, but always encode it. So i'd say, yeah, you have to get busy there and do some coding. Maybe have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294107/how-can-i-send-the-ampersand-character-via-ajax,  encodeURIComponent() seems to work.

Comment: I don't mind that, I just wanted to make sure that this is the case. And how would a replace should be done for the other side to get the proper value? I use Uri.EscapeUriString for encoding.

Comment: This is C#, not Javascript.

Comment: No problem, I think this is a server side issue, it just doesn't work with any encode that I apply to the JSON string.