# JS - How to move a JSON object's item to another position

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

I'm using JQuery sortable to reorder JSON object's items into a JSON array. So let's pretend I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID_id": "I3Y0RAmsr5",
        "DT_createdAt": "2020-12-02T14:39:24",
        "DT_updatedAt": "2020-12-02T14:39:42",
        "ST_text": "first",
        "NU_number": 1,
    },
    {
        "ID_id": "vL3cmiVvQv",
        "DT_createdAt": "2020-12-02T14:39:45",
        "DT_updatedAt": "2020-12-02T14:40:03",
        "ST_text": "second\n",
        "NU_number": 2,
    }
]
```

This is my code to get an array of moved keys:

```
// fetch data from Users.json
$data = file_get_contents('Users.json');
$data_array = json_decode($data, true);    

    <ul class="ui-sortable" id="sortableColumns">
     <?php foreach($data_array[0] as $k => $v) { ?>
       <li class="ui-sortable-handle" id="<?php echo $k ?>"><?php echo $k ?><i class="fas fa-grip-lines"></i></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    
   <script>
     $(function () {
       $('#sortableColumns').sortable({ update: function(event, ui) {
         var newOrderArray = $(this).find('li').map(function(i, el) {
            return $(el).attr('id');
         }).get()
         getJsonTableData(newOrderArray);
         }
       });
    });
     


    function getJsonTableData(newOrderArray) {
          console.log('newOrderArray: ' + newOrderArray);
          $.getJSON('Users.json', function (jsonData) {
             $.each(jsonData, function(j, obj){
               
// HERE I GUESS I NEED TO USE SOME CODE TO REORDER MY OBJECT'S ITEMS AND UPDATE THE Users.json FILE...

             });
          });
        }
  </script>
```

[image]

The console log I get after moving, for instance, the `ID_id` element to the bottom, is:

```
newOrderArray: DT_createdAt,DT_updatedAt,ST_text,NU_number,AR_array,ID_id
```

So, what I need to do now is to edit the `jsonData` array to look like this:

```
[
        {
            "DT_createdAt": "2020-12-02T14:39:24",
            "DT_updatedAt": "2020-12-02T14:39:42",
            "ST_text": "first",
            "NU_number": 1,
            "ID_id": "I3Y0RAmsr5" // -> key moved from to to bottom
        },
        {
            "DT_createdAt": "2020-12-02T14:39:45",
            "DT_updatedAt": "2020-12-02T14:40:03",
            "ST_text": "second\n",
            "NU_number": 2,
            "ID_id": "vL3cmiVvQv" // -> key moved from to to bottom
        }
    ]
```

And, of course, I need to update my `Users.json` file as shown above.

Comment: i dont understand why you want to reorder your json..its just what you want to display you want to reorder?  so you just adapt the visual, could you display your html?

Comment: I have a database based on JSON files, so what I want to do is to give users the possibility to reorder the table columns, and since the table is static, I'm using jQuery sortable to reorder the column names and then I need to process the JSON file with the new keys order, save it an reloasd the page so that columns are shown in the selected order. Hope it helps

Comment: have you access to the code of server?

Comment: Yes, it's my own backend, https://xserver.app if you want to check it out. Anyway, I simply need to update my JSON file based on the sorted columns (the keys) names.

Comment: yes i suppose you have lot of records, so you want to save the new visual or the user has to rebuild each time?

Comment: It's not just about adjusting the visual order of columns, I need to rebuild the JSON file accordingly to the order of the keys, because they also can download it and it must have the key:value order they set on my website

Comment: what is AR_array? its not include in json data?

Comment: Yes, i just haven’t posted it in the json example. That’s not important, I would just need to know if there’s a way to move objects items to different positions, even in php with an ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could change the order of json with [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/stringify):

```js
var $data_array = [
    {
        "ID_id": "I3Y0RAmsr5",
        "DT_createdAt": "2020-12-02T14:39:24",
        "DT_updatedAt": "2020-12-02T14:39:42",
        "ST_text": "first",
        "NU_number": 1,
    },
    {
        "ID_id": "vL3cmiVvQv",
        "DT_createdAt": "2020-12-02T14:39:45",
        "DT_updatedAt": "2020-12-02T14:40:03",
        "ST_text": "second\n",
        "NU_number": 2,
    }
];



var newOrderArray= ["DT_createdAt","DT_updatedAt","ST_text","NU_number","ID_id"];

var newjson = JSON.stringify( $data_array, newOrderArray);
var newarray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( $data_array, newOrderArray));

console.log(newjson);
console.log(newarray);
```

Comment: Hi @Frenchy, I have a weird issue using that code for values that have the ‘&’ as character in a string value, if I launch that code, the json gets null and erases all key:values. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: its normal its problem of encoding:    replace "&" by %26 or use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707854/proper-way-to-handle-the-ampersand-character-in-json-string-send-to-rest-web-ser

Comment: you could encode the value: encodeURIComponent(value),   $.get("/?act=" + value,(data)..