# Recieving AJAX JSON including `&` symbol in JOOMLA

Tags: php, ajax, json, joomla, joomla3.0

following is my string after JSON.stringify

```
"chk={
    "node":"obj.1.46971",
    "user":"arslan",
    "to":"mercedes",
    "article":"<p>this my test&nbsp;</p>",
    "subject":"haha",
    "comments":"hello"
}"
```

I am sending it through AJAX to my JOOMLA controller

When I try to recieve `chk` in my JOOMLA controller it clips at `&` symbol and  recieves only  `

```
"chk{
    "node":"obj.1.46971",
    "user":"arslan",
    "to":"mercedes",
    "article":"<p>this my test`
```

following is the line of code that I am using to receive post variables

```
$myJson=$app->input->get("chk","undefined",'RAW');
```

So how should I resolve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I send the "&" (ampersand) character via AJAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294107/how-can-i-send-the-ampersand-character-via-ajax)

Comment: should i delete it @Quentin

Comment: or as it is help users short list the search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i just found it after making JSON use this to escape URI special chracters like ampersand

```
encodeURIComponent('&')
```

for details
[How can I send the "&" (ampersand) character via AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294107/how-can-i-send-the-ampersand-character-via-ajax)