# Escaping Special Character Java JSON

Tags: java, json

Hi I am trying to send a JSON object to the server. The JSON object is :

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject("{'Hobbies':" + h + "}");

{"Hobbies" : "Programming & Gaming"}
```

But as I SEND this object via HTTP it gives me an error Unterminated Object at character 22. After a lot of research I found out the '&' splits the object. Is there anyway I can escape '&'. I tried '\&' but it doesn't work as there is no escape sequence like that.

Comment: `After a lot of research I found out the '&' splits the object.` Show us your sources. What does _splits the object_ mean?

Comment: Try escaping the \. `'\\&'`

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to escape a `&` in JSON.

Comment: @Sotirios Well apparently it does have some purpose if it breaks the JSON.

Comment: @Pietu1998 I'm still not convinced that's the problem here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The programme works just fine if there is no '&' present. Eg {"Hobbies" : "Programming"} this will work just fine but gives an error if I use '&'

Comment: Show us the exact error. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Just thought of something. If you send that JSON string value through HTTP, it'll break like this: `json={"foo":"bar & baz"}` to `json={"foo":"bar `and baz"}, effectively making `json` contain an unterminated JSON string. Pardon my formatting, the backticks seem to hate me.

Comment: @Pietu Brings up a good point. Describe _as I send this object_.

Comment: @Sotirios Actually figured out using [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294107/how-can-i-send-the-ampersand-character-via-ajax) found via googling.  The problem may be somewhere else, so not flagging a dupe. (not that it would be too much of one anyway.)

Comment: Can you please be more detailed? How do you send it? In the body? As part of the query string? What gives you the error? What is the exact error?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The exact error is : System.err org.json.JSONException : Unterminated Object at character 22 of {'Hobbies' : Programming & Gaming}

Comment: Please edit your question and add it there with the full stacktrace.

Comment: And that error is because the string value is not enclosed in quotes.  Character 22 is at the end of "Programming".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to json.org and study the syntax *carefully*.  A key or string value in JSON must be enclosed in double quotes.  Your code is generating

```
{'Hobbies' : Programming & Gaming}
```

To do it the way you're doing it you need to escape the double quotes:

```
new JSONObject("{\"Hobbies\":\"" + h + "\"}");
```

However, it would be far better to construct a JSONObject out of separate key and value.  I'm not sure which specific Java JSON package you're using, but for most this would be simply:

```
new JSONObject("Hobbies", h);
```

Comment: This library is pretty bad and allows you to use the `String` literal  `"{\"Hobbies\" : Programming & Gaming}"` as a JSON string.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Yes, that's a valid string in JSON, but not valid JSON.  It's just a string -- could just as well be "How now brown cow".

Comment: I'm saying the parsing is very loose. It will not complain or fail given that value as its single constructor argument, although it is invalid JSON.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis -- There are at least two different Java JSON packages that have the JSONObject class, so we don't know which is being used here.  I would not trust one that treated `{"Hobbies" : Programming & Gaming}` as valid JSON, though.

Comment: In any case, the parsing wouldn't fail at `&`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so what do you use as a json library? I use `org.json` but I hear a lot about `GSON` and `Jackson` but Im not sure which one to use

Comment: I've tried all `org.json` versions on [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) and they all pass at parsing the `String` value previously mentioned.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah you were right I missed the quotes, the reason the '&' didn't work was without the quotes '&' was acting as a special character.