# Ajax sending datastring error when a variable contains amparsand

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making a program to submit a form with Ajax By combining all values in variable datastring and sending it with ajax method..

suppose

```
var varname="ram";
var varage=18;

and var datastring='name='+varname+'&age='+varage;
```

This works well but

```
var varname="ram & shyam";
var varage=18;

and var datastring='name='+varname+'&age='+varage;
```

When a variable already contain & in it then value received by php code as $_POST['name'] has value only 'ram' not 'ram & shyam'

Please tell a solution for this problem

Comment: use `%26`  instead of &

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
 var varname="ram & shyam";
 var sendData = varname.replace("&","%26");
```

another useful links

[How can I send the "&" (ampersand) character via AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294107/how-can-i-send-the-ampersand-character-via-ajax)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

Replace & with %26 while sending the data

```
var varname="ram & shyam";
var varage=18;

var newvarname=varname.replace("&","%26");
var datastring='name='+newvarname+'&age='+varage;
```