# Ajax and ASP.NET full string not being sent properly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ajax call like so:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/connection/NotifiyNextDepartment?questionId=" 
             + highestValue + "&department=" + jobTitle + "&customerId=" + customerID + "&jobNumber=" 
             + $("#communtiyDropdown").val() + $("#lotDropdown").val(),
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {}
    });

    alert('Success, you\'re data has been saved!');

    holder = [];
},
failure: function (errMsg) {
    alert('Failed, somthing went wrong, please try again!');
}
```

`jobTitle` is equal to "Human Resources & Customer Experience Manager"

when I send it to .NET I only get this back:

```
public bool NotifiyNextDepartment(int questionid, string department, int customerId, string jobNumber)
{
}
```

Here `department` is equal to "Human Resources "

Why is .NET removing everything after the & and how do I fix this?

Comment: You'll need to encode the values. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11294181/433234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should call [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on your parameters.

```
url: "/api/connection/NotifiyNextDepartment?questionId=" 
         + encodeURIComponent(highestValue) + "&department=" + encodeURIComponent(jobTitle) + "&customerId=" + encodeURIComponent(customerID) + "&jobNumber=" 
         + encodeURIComponent($("#communtiyDropdown").val() + $("#lotDropdown").val()),
```